# The infinite intersection of almost all cosets modulo $p_n \#$ is infinite? How can we prove this...

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, integers

Let $A(n) = $ a union of cosets of $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n = p_n\#$ such that $A(1) = p_1\Bbb{Z}$ and $A(n) = A(n-1)\cap (p_n\Bbb{Z} \cup \bigcup_{k = 2}^{p_n -2} (p_n\Bbb{Z} + k))$

Since we're taking (almost all) cosets modulo $p_n$ and intersecting with previous cases, and "almost all" cosets unioned together make up most of $\Bbb{Z}$, then intuitively, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A(n)$ is an infinite set.  However, how can we formally prove that indeed $|A(\infty)| = \infty$ since both the moduli $M_n = p_n\#$ and the minimal coset reprsentative $|x_n|$ other than $0$ grows with $n$?

The minimal coset representative $|x_n|$ such that $x_n + M_n\Bbb{Z}$ appears in the expanded union for $A(n)$ grows much slower than the moduli $M_n$.  The total number of cosets in the union for $A(n)$ is exactly $f(1) = 1$, $f(n) = f(n-1)(p_n - 2), n \geq 2$, which can be proved using the Chinese remainder theorem.

This is such a brain twister!  It's as if we're missing some notion that's like asymptotic density but for handling this special case.  We can't use asymptotic density directly because $A(n)$ is not a fixed set but a sequence of sets.

I am now thinking along the lines of the proportion:

$$
g(n) = \dfrac{(p_2 - 2) (p_3 - 2) \cdots (p_n - 2)}{p_2 p_3 \cdots p_n}
$$

which I believe should approach $1$, right?

Comment: The quantity $g(n)$ tends to $0$ at a rate of roughly $O(1/(\ln n)^2)$.

Comment: @ErickWong in other words, that proportion can't be used in a proof of infinitude of $|A(\infty)|$.

Comment: Correct.  I think this is essentially a question about residues of twin primes.

Comment: @ErickWong yes it is.

Comment: @ErickWong could you expand upon your idea in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’m reading this correctly you are looking for the set of integers $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$ for every odd prime $p$.  But this means that $n^2 - 1$ is not divisible by any odd primes, and is hence a power of $2$.  By Mihailescu’s theorem (or more elementary results), this only happens for $n = 0, \pm3$.

Since $A(1)$ filters out odd numbers we are left with $A(\infty) = \{0\}$.  (I guess we didn’t really need Mihailescu with this parity restriction: it’s obvious that $n^2 -1$ is divisible by some odd prime when $n$ is nonzero and even.)

Comment: I am not seeing how Mihailescu's theorem shows this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: @OlympicComputerChairSitter We are solving $n^2 - 1 = 2^k$.  Calculate small values of $k$ manually.  For any $k \ge 2$, Mihailescu applies since $n^2$ and $2^k$ are both perfect powers separated by $1$.